# org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?

Tags: scribe, android-twitter

I am getting the following exception when I use scribe library for posting image to twitter

```
org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?
```

I am using scribe1.3.3 library.

I searched in google for this Exception ,but didnt find any solution.

Source Code:

```
  OAuthService oAuth = new ServiceBuilder()
                    .provider(TwitterApi.class)
                    .apiKey("6JyIkj71ZqG4wk3YF0Y4hw")        // REPLACE WITH YOUR OWN!!!
                    .apiSecret("sJl9aRVqlEt7nxlKvpMVK6tLULz5FSQ2KUOW0yie4")  // REPLACE WITH YOUR OWN!!!
                    .callback(TwitterDialog.redirectedurl)             // REPLACE WITH YOUR OWN!!!
                    .build();
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(TwitterDialog.redirectedurl);
            Token requestToken = new Token( uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token"),uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier"));
            Verifier verifier = new Verifier(uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier"));
if(verifier!=null){
                Log.e("verifier created","created");
            }

            Token accesstoken=oAuth.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);


            Log.e("raw resp", accesstoken.getRawResponse());

 if(accesstoken!=null){

           Log.e("hello","hhello");
         Log.e("access token","hi"+accesstoken.toString());
        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json");



    oAuth.signRequest(accesstoken, request);  // ENTER USER'S ACCESS TOKEN

// ADD MULTIPART FORM

    try
    {
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

        entity.addPart("status", new StringBody("insert vacuous statement here"));       // THIS IS THE TWITTER MESSAGE
        entity.addPart("media", new FileBody(new File("/storage/sdcard0/HelloAlbum/1361964305003.jpg")));  // THIS IS THE PHOTO TO UPLOAD

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        entity.writeTo(out);

        request.addPayload(out.toByteArray());
        request.addHeader(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

// SEND REQUEST

    try {JSONObject response = new JSONObject (request.send().getBody());}
    catch (JSONException e) {Log.e("TOUR_APP_TAG", "JSONException Thrown: " + e.getMessage());}

   }
```

Logcat output:

```
     03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777): org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract token and secret from this: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777): <hash>
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):   <request>/oauth/access_token</request>
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):   <error>Invalid / expired Token</error>
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777): </hash>
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777): '
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:41)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at org.scribe.extractors.TokenExtractorImpl.extract(TokenExtractorImpl.java:27)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:103)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:84)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getAccessToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:89)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at com.android.twitter.TwitterActivity$1.onComplete(TwitterActivity.java:317)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at com.twitter.android.TwitterApp$1.handleMessage(TwitterApp.java:236)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-05 15:52:24.810: E/AndroidRuntime(28777):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It says "expired token" in the error message. Also, don't put your credentials in the code sample.

Comment: What should I change in this code?

Comment: The `requestToken` you're getting as a parameter is outdated. You should try with a fresh one. I don't understand your code so I can't tell you exactly what to change.